# Error: The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, char

Tags: if-statement, operators

I keep getting this error message when I want to check the value of a char in a char array.

```
if(word[0] == 'A'||'E')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if(word[0] == 'A' || word[0] == 'E')`. Depending on the language, more elegant solutions might exist.

Comment: What that code says is `if(word[0] == true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you want:

if ( word[0] == 'A' || word[0] == 'E' )

You can't use a Boolean 'OR' with two character operands, which is what your code is attempting. Instead, you need to apply it to two Boolean expressions, as I've done. Hope that helps!